# CSS - Buttons' background colors' dont change on mobile

Tags: css, button, mobile, submit

[image]

The left one is on computer and right one is on mobile. 
I dont want the mobile on to have a gradient background or round edges.

```
input {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    background: green;
    color: lime;
    height: 40px;
    width: 123px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that on mobile devices like the iPhone and other apple products which use safari have different formats for input including the rounded edge. The easiest way around this would be to just create image with a onclick function. Like so, or onmouseover for a hover effect.

```
<script>
function myfunction(){

}
</script>

<img src="picture.png" onclick="myfunction();" onmouseover="this.src='image2.gif'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set attribute "-webkit-appearance" to "none":

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```